# How to move one file from a directory to another on vba using just partial string of the file name?

Tags: excel, vba, object

I have a report that is generated daily and automatically. I need a code that moves the file from one directory to another, taking in account that I need to use it daily, and only a part of the file name is constant (the rest varies each day without a defined pattern).

I would be very gradeful for your help, I'm a beginner on vba and I need help, if you need additional explanation ask me for it.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try the code below:

```
Sub Move_Folder()

    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim SourcePath As String
    Dim DestPath As String
    Dim NameFile as String

    SourcePath = "C:\Users\Adhy\"  '<< Change as needed
    DestPath = "C:\Users\Mauro\"    '<< Change as needed
    NameFile  = "Sheet_1*.xl*"      '<< Change as needed

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(Left(SourcePath,Len(SourcePath)-1)) = False Then
        MsgBox SourcePath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'to move
    FSO.MoveFile Source:=SourcePath & NameFile , Destination:=DestPath

End Sub
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand where I have to write the part of the file name that the code has to recognize to move the object. is it in ``Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")``? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my code. Please use the new one.

Comment: Thank you, it worked, 

But what I was asking for is the following: imagine that my file name is "sheet_1_09062017", and I want to move it from on folder to another with a code that uses only the first part of the file name: "Sheet_1" because the last part varies every day the report is generated on the folder, what can I do?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can changed NameFile  = "TestFile.xlsx" to NameFile  = "Sheet_1*.xlsx"

Comment: Or NameFile  = "Sheet_1*.xl*"

Comment: Sorry, I am not explainin good myself, I don't need to rename the file, I need a code which detects the file it has to move only using the first part of the name, in other words, a code that detects the first part of the name "sheet_1" and moves the file which has it to another folder without changing the original name, may be I can do something creating string variables?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please see the new vba code I provided.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
Sub formatchange()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("your path")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'for a faster code
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
       If InStr(1, objFile.Name, "searched value") > 0 Then
         objFSO.MoveFile objFile, "yournewpath"
       End If
    Next

    'Clean up!
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turn on updatin again
End Sub
```

Comment: Tank you very much it worked